# Distributed rendering in adobe premiere cs 6

Tags: subpixel-rendering

Does adobe premiere cs 6 supports distributed rendering? I have been searching and have found very few info about it. If it does, could you point me to a tutorial on how to set it up?

Answer (score 1):

CS6 does not appear to offer distributed rendering as such. Premiere CS6 via the Media Encoder (which all Adobe video apps can use), can render your work in the background though, which may help:
http://tv.adobe.com/watch/cs6-creative-cloud-feature-tour-for-video/save-time-with-powerful-background-rendering-using-media-encoder/

Hopefully this helps, David